# How can I backup windows 10 for linux virtualbox?

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox

I am migrating from Windows 10 to Linux. I want to use my current Windows 10 on Linux Virtual Box. How can I create a system image that has all my files and programs?

I can back up my windows 10 to hard drive with the following link.
Control Panel\System and Security\Backup and Restore (Windows 7).

But I don't know how can I use this backup files to run windows 10 on Linux virtual box machine?

[image: These files]

Comment: See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/614400/how-can-i-clone-a-hard-drive-directly-to-a-vdi-image#614688). However, you Win10 is going to have a lot of excess luggage (plenty of useless hardware support, all the apps that you are going to use only on Linux...). The smaller, the better.

Comment: Thanks. I have a lot of games and Visual Studio on Windows 10. Can Linux Wine run all of this applications?I think that the virtual box is a good investment for Linux? Am I wrong?

Comment: Not sure the games will be supported in the Vbox, AFAIK the 3D support for video isn't very good, when it exists at all. One thing you can try is to install a Windows VBox under you existing Windows host, and install one of your games and check.