# How to move an existing Ubuntu OS on an SSD to virtual drive through a USB

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I am just trying to run an existing Ubuntu install that was on another laptop through a USB using VirtualBox in another machine.

I want to be able to move any hard drive from another machine to VirtualBox on Windows 10. Is there any way to do that?

I have been searching online but it doesn't seem to be something that can be done on VirtualBox.

I thought of installing Ubuntu on external hard drive then move the files from the other machine but this way seems to be very time-consuming.

I would appreciate any insight!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clone a hard drive directly to a vdi image](https://superuser.com/questions/614400/how-can-i-clone-a-hard-drive-directly-to-a-vdi-image)

Comment: I marked this as duplicate, but in general you want to use `VBoxManage convertfromraw [mounted file system path] [VDI filename for output] --format VDI`. Remember, Ubuntu is Linux and Linux systems are relatively easy to dupe from one disk to another.

Comment: I don't want to clone or duplicate but rather I want to load the Ubuntu OS from the USB and then load it on my VirtualBox on Win 10. Is it possible to do that?